# How to use Qualtrics' graphics from URL option to pull from GitHub graphics

Tags: url, github, graphics, qualtrics

I have a PDF on GitHub, and everything I try is not referencing a raw image, but downloading one instead.  Qualtrics hence does not recognise the image as it is actually a download link.

I have tried

```
https://github.com/user/repo-name/blob/master/picture.pdf
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blob/master/picture.pdf
```

Neither of which is working.  I don't want to download these locally as they may change with the repo.  Would anyone be able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: a PDF is not an image format, hence, Qualtrics does not embed it.  I converted it to a png, and used

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blob/master/picture.png
```